# Using CSS, checkbox and selectors to control visibility of form field

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to use a checkbox to control the visibility of a field. The code below works fine but I want ideally to put the checkbox & label fields in a paragraph tag so I can style and add padding etc.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cbx" name="cbx"><label for="cbx">Different drop off location?</label>
<div class="testerclass"><p>Some text here</p></div>


input[type=checkbox] + label {
    color:#000000;
    font-weight:bold;} 

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label ~ .testerclass {
    display:inline;}
```

When I add the paragraph tag around it stops working. I can see the reason for this is that the checkbox no longer has the same parent as the div I'm wanting to display, but I can't work out how to do this in CSS because I need to refer to the state of the checkbox. Can anyone help at all? Thank you.

```
<p class="styletoline"><input type="checkbox" id="cbx" name="cbx"><label for="cbx">Different drop off location?</label>
<div class="testerclass"><p>Some text here</p></div></p>
```

Comment: you cannot insert a div or a paragraph inside another paragraph, so change the markup - then validate your code

Comment: You dont need to have a paragraph to style it with padding etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to change your paragraph into a div. You cannot have a div or paragraph inside another paragraph.

Therefore you might change it to:

```
<div class="styletoline">
    <input type="checkbox" id="cbx" name="cbx">
    <label for="cbx">Different drop off location?</label>
    <div class="testerclass">
        <p>Some text here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can now change your styletoline like any other css class

```
.styletoline { 
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: HI, thanks for this. I think I got distracted looking at the input[type=checkbox]:checked code in the CSS rather than being more basic with the main code and styling round with an overall div.